# how i can convert this request call in javascript to ajax code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a request code in te javascript .. and i want to convert it to ajax call .. because i think that my code is very old ? can you help please ?

my function in the js is :

```
            function loadRest() {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            let result = parseResponse(this.status, this.responseText);
            if (result != null) {
                Rest.rests = result;
                createTable();
            }
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", Rest.baseURL + "/byCompany/" + logginedCompanyId, true);
    request.send();
} 


function parseResponse(status, responseText) {
    log(responseText);
    let responseObject = JSON.parse(responseText);
    if (status !== 200 || (responseObject.error && responseObject.error != null)) {
        alert("Error: " + responseObject.error);
        return null;
    }
    return responseObject.result;
}
```

Comment: It's already an Ajax call. Do you mean convert it to using `$.ajax` from the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

you can use $.get()
something like this

$.get('Rest.baseURL', function(response){

//

});

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you wanted.

```
$('#ajax').click(function() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "localhost:8080/restws/json/product/get",
        success: function(data){
            let result = JSON.parse(data);
            if(result != null) {
                Rest.rests = result;
                createTable();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i want like that : 
    $('#ajax').click(function(){ 
        alert('ajax');
         $.ajax({ 
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "json",
             url: "http://localhost:8080/restws/json/product/get",
             success: function(data){        
                alert(data);
             }
         });
    });